# Global object is undefined even after updating it in a function

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, processing, p5.js

Being a user of C++, and completely new to web-dev I am unable to understand why does the global variable 'angle' not get updated inside the function setup(). Because, in the last line where I run console.log(angle[1].arc_colour), it returns me undefined. However, if I try to print the same command in the console, a finite number is returned.

(NOTE: setup() is a function in p5.js which gets called first upon each execution)

```js
//quick.js
var angle = new Array(200);

function Drawn_Arc(begin_angle, end_angle, arc_colour) {
    this.begin_angle = begin_angle;
    this.end_angle = end_angle;
    this.arc_colour = arc_colour;
}

function swap(a, b) {
    a = a + b;
    b = a - b;
    a = a - b;
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    background(230);
    noStroke();
    colorMode(HSL, 2000);
    for (let i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
        angle[i - 1] = new Drawn_Arc(((i - 1) * PI) / 100, (i * PI) / 100, random(0, 2000));
        fill(angle[i - 1].arc_colour, 2000, 1000);
        arc(windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2, windowHeight - 12, windowHeight - 12, angle[i - 1].begin_angle, angle[i - 1].end_angle, PIE);
    }
}
console.log(angle[1].arc_colour);
```

```html
//---html---
<html style="margin : 0px; padding : 0px">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Quick Sort</title>
</head>

<body style="margin : 0px; padding : 0px">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="quick.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] global variable 'angle' not get updated inside the function `setup()`. Because, in the last line where I run `console.log(angle[1].arc_colour)`, it returns me undefined.

The line `onsole.log(angle[1].arc_colour);` is not in the `setup` function, but it's at the end of the script in global scope.

Move `console.log(angle[1].arc_colour);` into the setup function, so that it is done after the array was initialized:

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    background(230);
    noStroke();
    colorMode(HSL, 2000);
    for (let i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
        angle[i - 1] = new Drawn_Arc(((i - 1) * PI) / 100, (i * PI) / 100, random(0, 2000));
        fill(angle[i - 1].arc_colour, 2000, 1000);
        arc(windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2, windowHeight - 12,
            windowHeight - 12, angle[i - 1].begin_angle, angle[i - 1].end_angle, PIE);
    }

    console.log(angle[1].arc_colour);
}
// console.log(angle[1].arc_colour);
```

---

> What if I wanted to use the array in some other function. How would I do that?

Of course you can log the array in a function, too:

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    // ......

    logarray();
}

function logarray()
{
    console.log(angle[1].arc_colour);
}
```

Comment: What I really want is to have access to the angle array globally, how could we do that, also I have added `var angle = new Array();` as told by you earlier

Comment: @ManasSingh You have access to the array. But the array is not initialized before `setup` is not done, you don't have "access" to the first element, because it doesn't exist at this time point. What do you want to achieve? What about access in `function draw(){ }` ?

Comment: It worked! draw() being a looping function, began printing the value again and again, why is it so? What if I wanted to use the array in some other function. How would I do that? Provided that I want to use it post it is updated inside the function setup() - @Rabbid76

Comment: @ManasSingh I extended the answer.